# My laptop's mousepad doesn't work after I installed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mousepad

I connected USB mouse and it works. But I want to use the mousepad of my laptop.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Im using dell inspiron 14

Answer (score 0):

In general, a little bit more information is needed in order to have an idea of the computer you are running. Although most hardware is supported in linux nowadays, it does not mean that yours is fully supported. What was the laptop running before you installed ubuntu 14, was it another linux distribution where the touchpad was working?

The fact that it does not work could mean that you may need a more recent distribution for that hardware (What made you think that ubuntu 14 was fully supported?).

About debugging touchpads in general, some useful reading can be found here: [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection)

On my laptop if i run

cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i touch

I get the following device N: Name="AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad"

What do you get?

Be aware that in some HP laptops, there is a button (often on the touchpad itself) which will turn off the touchpad -- unlikely for that to be your problem, I thought it worth mentioning.

Cheers.

Comment: mine is Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad", ok i will try to find the solution

Comment: I found this (http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201101-6952/) that suggests your device should be definitely supported. Did the touchpad work during the installation? Look into /var/log/Xorg.0.log (or similar) and try to find a line for synaptics driver if it is not being loaded, that could be an indication. There should be a package installed on your machine with xserver-xorg-input-synaptics, if it is not you might need to install it.

Answer (score -1):

Try going to "Mouse and touchpad" in your settings and should be a button to enable or disable the touchpad.

Comment: sadly, it didn't work

Comment: Sorry man, maybe someone else can help you